# Radio Button Control in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp-classic

I'm new to Web development and jQuery.
I'm trying to build an ASPX page with two `RadioButton` controls that must perform the following actions:

On page load, one of the two must be selected depending on a flag from an object on the ASPX page. Lets call it customer.Id. If the Id is true, select `RadioButton` one must be set else select `RadioButton` 2 must be set.

At any point after page load the user selects a `RadioButton`, the other must be deselected.

When `RadioButton` two is clicked, hide a `Table` named "employee table" and when `RadioButton` one is clicked, show that `Table`.

Can anyone please tell me how I can get this functionality in jQuery functions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide an example? Also, radio buttons, if grouped under the same `name`, only one can be selected.

Comment: Further to what elclanrs said, if you show your HTML that gives us something to work with in JS/jQuery.

Comment: the radio buttons are seperately added to the page using syntax similar to <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" /> and same with the table i am trying to hide and show based upon which radio button is pressed. so both buttons have a distinct name

Comment: _"both buttons have a distinct name"_ - do you mean the radio buttons have different names, or they share the same name that is distinct from other controls' names? If you give both radios the same name attribute they will operate as a group such that clicking one automatically deselects the other - you can still distinguish between them in JS by giving them different ids and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about .NET but in Classic ASP you would write a variable like this <%=customerID%>.

In jQuery, I think you can do something like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1"> Yes
<input type="radio" id="radio2"> No

<table border="1" id="employeeTable">
    <tr><td>This is the table</td></tr>
</table>
```

... and then some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var customerID = <%=customerID%> // asp variable

    if (customerID != "") {
        $('#radio1').prop('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('#radio2').prop('checked', 'checked');
    }

    $('#radio1').click(function() {
        $('#employeeTable').fadeIn('fast');
    })

    $('#radio2').click(function() {
        $('#employeeTable').fadeOut('fast');
    })
})
```

You can have a look/play here: http://jsfiddle.net/qcLtX/7/

Try changing the customerID value to nothing, like `var customerID = ""`.

Good luck

**UPDATE**

Where I have used `.prop`: If you are using jQuery version 1.6 or greater, you should use `.prop`, otherwise, use `.attr`.

Comment: Well done for pointing out the difference between prop and attr :)

Answer (score -1):

Radio buttons are grouped by their *name* attribute, like so ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)).

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
</form>
```

If the radio buttons are grouped, then selecting any one of them automatically delselects all the others in that group.

So the buttons cannot have a distinct name. If you want to distinguish between radio buttons (without referring the their value), you should add an id.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="m" value="male" />
```

You can set the selected radio button on page load declaratively in markup, or using jquery.

Declarative version:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="sex" value="male" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#m").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```